# sprite kit swift boundary for the scene

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

this is a objective-c code that work exactly for physics body  collision around the screen

```
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(10.0f, -10.0f);
    //  Create a physics body  borders the screen
    SKPhysicsBody* borderBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    //  Set physicsBody of scene to borderBody
    self.physicsBody = borderBody;

    SKSpriteNode* aa = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ca1.png"];
    aa.position = CGPointMake(20, 20);
    aa.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:aa.frame.size.width/2];

    aa.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
    aa.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0f;
    aa.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0f;

    [self addChild:aa];
```

that should be the equivalent for swift

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(CGFloat(10.0), CGFloat(-10.0));
let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
self.physicsBody = physicsBody

var sp=SKSpriteNode()
var atexture=SKTexture(imageNamed: "candycane.png")
sp=SKSpriteNode(texture: atexture)
sp.position=CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

     sp.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:  bird.size.height / 2)
    sp.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    sp.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    sp.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0

    self.addChild(sp)
```

but work only for top and bottom the spritenode can go out the left and right

what is the problem ?.
how i can have a boundary for the scene in swift ?.

Comment: You're not seeing the entire scene. Try selecting the Rotate Left option from the Simulator's Hardware menu. BTW, you're also mixing sp and bird.

Comment: sp and bird its only wrong because i changed for here.

Comment: dont think that Rotate Left its the solution the code in  objective-c work perfectly in landscape and portrait

Comment: I implemented your code. The boundary is there. The default scene is set up for landscape, but you're viewing it in portrait mode.

Comment: no rotating Left  the Simulator the problem remain

Comment: Add this to your didMoveToView: println ("width = \(self.frame.width) height = \(self.frame.height)")

Comment: If the width is larger than the height and you're in portrait mode, you're not seeing the entire scene.

Comment: so say me why in objective-c work i test every2 in the same way in emulator

Comment: and when node go out of screen will be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so this is the magic trick

lets add this in GameViewController

```
let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
```

end get the same result of the objective-c all work fine

Comment: Can you please print some code of your GameViewController? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that this swift code can't do the same effect to te next objective-c code

```
let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
self.physicsBody = physicsBody
```

objective-c code

```
SKPhysicsBody* borderBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
self.physicsBody = borderBody;
```

objective-c code work swift no

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will helpfull for you in Swift for Side and top bottom sprite collision.

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody ( edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame )
```

Answer (score 0):

for the moment i solved with this

```
let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFromRect: CGRect(x: 300, y: 0, width: self.size.width-600, height: self.size.height))
```

and get the same result of objective-c code in the iphone 6 simulator but this its very bad solution

i will do that whit the right way

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going into your `GameViewController` and setting the following:

`scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill`

I had a similar issue and this fixed it for me.